# Cloud Functions for Firebase: Enumerate DataSnapshot Properties

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to iterate over DataSnapshot properties in my Firebase function. Here's my code.

```js
alignmentsRef.once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(k) {
        var itemId = k.key //itemId
        var childData = k.val() //{downvotes: {memberId: "down"}, upvotes: {memberId: "up"}}
        var memberIds = childData.downvotes // {memberId: "down"}
        memberIds.forEach(l => {
            ...
        })
    })
```

It doesn't seem like `memberIds` is enumerable because I get the error:

> memberIds.forEach is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memberIds` will be an `Object` - not an `Array` - so you cannot enumerate it using `forEach`. You can, however, access it as a snapshot using [`child`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#child):

```
alignmentsRef
  .once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (k) {
        k.child('downvotes').forEach(function (d) {
          console.log(`${d.key} = ${d.val()}`);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I can't believe I didn't realize I was doing this. I'm trying to translate a function I'm using in node to a Firebase Cloud Function. The original uses uses Object.keys() to get the keys, then iterates over them. I'd forgotten that Object.keys() also outputs an array.